# (Vanilla Javascript) Applying a function to areas of the document depending on the location of the event handler

Tags: javascript, html

I think jQuery can do this effectively with [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/), but I'm searching for a vanilla javascript solution for learning's sake. Here's the relevant blocks:

The HTML

```
<div class="collapse-boxes-and-form-section">
  <div class="collapse-boxes-column">
    <h2 class="collapse-boxes-h2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</h2>
    <a onClick="collapseboxtoggle()">
    <div class="icon-collapse-box">
      <img class="icon-collapse-icon" src="/assets/img/pageimg/image.png" width="70px">
      <h4 class="icon-collapse-box-title">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</h4>
      <p class="icon-collapse-box-p" style="height:auto">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
    </div>
    </a>
    <a onClick="collapseboxtoggle()">
    <div class="icon-collapse-box collasped-box">
        <img class="icon-collapse-icon" src="/assets/img/pageimg/image.png" width="60px">
        <h4 class="icon-collapse-box-title">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</h4>
        <p class="icon-collapse-box-p">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

In a nutshell, I'm attempting to expand and collapse the words within the ".icon-collapse-box-p" class when the ".icon-collapse-box" class is clicked. The function seems to be working (although cluttered), but I need it to expand and collapse depending on which particular ".icon-collapse-box" is clicked without adding unique classnames for each box and duplicating the function.

The JS

```
    function collapseboxtoggle() {
    var nav = document.querySelector(".icon-collapse-box-p");
    if (nav.style.height === "auto") {
        nav.style.height = "0px";
        nav.style.gridRowStart = "2";
        nav.style.opacity = "0";
        nav.style.lineHeight = "0";
        nav.style.marginTop = "-21px";
    } else {
        nav.style.height = "auto";
        nav.style.gridRowStart = "2";
        nav.style.opacity = "1";
        nav.style.lineHeight = "2.0";
        nav.style.marginTop = "0px";
    }
}
```

Here's a couple of things I thought could help, but wasn't successful in implementing (from lack of know-how or otherwise):

[Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

[document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Anything outside of jQuery that'll help here?

Made this codepen if it'll help: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RMjXmJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, update your HTML part. Add "event" to your function calls:

```
<a onClick="collapseboxtoggle(event)">
```

Than on Javascript you can use that parameter to get what DOM element is clicked, so you can search for your element in this DOM

```
function collapseboxtoggle(e) {
    var box = e.currentTarget;
    var nav = box.getElementsByClassName("icon-collapse-box-p")[0];
```

It can be more elegant, but right now it works

Comment: Thanks - this worked. There's a severe lack of documentation on Event.currentTarget... it was hard to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Welcome. Yeah, missing part is how to send Event object from HTML. Faster (and less elegant) option is to send "this" in HTML functions, instead of "event", so you will have in your function direct reference to DOM (without calling currentTarget)

Comment: That makes sense - yeah. What is the purpose of the "[0]" there at the end of the var nav? I noticed when I changed that to any other number the function stops working.

Comment: getElementsByClassName("icon-collapse-box-p")  returns Array of elements that have "icon-collapse-box-p" as CSS class name. I expect that you **always** have at least one, so you get first element that is found. The best practice is first to check if response have more than one element and than take first. In other case you will get exception